# The notion of metrizable topological space?

Tags: general-topology

What is the simplest way to explain metrizable topological space along with theorem and properties in detail what are the applications 
Is metric topology and metrizable topological space same?

Comment: Read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem) first and then ask a question about what you don't understand.

Comment: can i know what are the application of metrizable topological space ?

Comment: There are no "applications". That a space is metrisable is an important property to know about it, because it implies that many other theorems can be applied to it.

Comment: A metric space has a *given* metric, and a metrisable space has an "optional" metric. The topologies behave the same otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A metrizable space is one for which it is possible to define a metric such that the metric topology coincides with the space's topology.

Urysohnn's metrization theorem gives some conditions under which a topological space is metrizable.  It is, I believe, one of the two biggest theorems in general topology (the other being Tychonoff's theorem, which has to do with compactness).